# Unable to resume activity - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I know this is quite a common question, but I have searched around and my attempts to solve the below issue have been unsuccessful.

In particular, below are the messages that I am receiving from logcat.

```
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1286
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.MatchingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2788)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at com.dooba.beta.MatchingActivity.onResume(MatchingActivity.java:82)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
08-03 17:55:53.885: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     ... 12 more
```

Below is the code for the activity

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    mUsers = users;
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });

        //This give you a list of  users. Then to access one user you need to know the index the user is  at.

        ParseUser user = mUsers.get(5); 

        //then you can access that user's information

        user.getString("name");
        user.getNumber("age"); 
        user.getString("headline");
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**Updated code:**
Error received
for the line

```
mUsers = new List<ParseUser>();
```

I receive the following messages:
"Cannot instantiate the type List<ParseUser>"

for the lines

```
 user.getString("name");
 user.getNumber("age"); 
 user.getString("headline");
```

I receive the following error:
"user cannot be resolved"

Thanks in advance, and below is the complete updated code.

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

    protected ParseRelation<ParseUser> mFriendsRelation;
    protected ParseUser mCurrentUser;   
    protected List<ParseUser> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
         //create list variable
        mUsers = new List<ParseUser>(); 

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mCurrentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    //add all the users to your list variable 
                    mUsers.addAll(users); 

                } else {
                    // Something went wrong.
                }
            }
        });

        //check the size of your list to see how big it is before accessing it
        final int size = mUsers.size(); 

        //or use a loop to loop through each one
        for(ParseUser mParseUser : mUsers) {
            //skip over the current user
            if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
                continue; 

            user.getString("name");
            user.getNumber("age"); 
            user.getString("headline");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: which line in the code is (MatchingActivity.java:82) ?

Comment: what if e!=null and mUsers is empty, referencing it in ParseUser user = mUsers.get(5);  would give NullPointer .

Comment: Did you call getWindow someplace?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. One important note is that I do not want to retrieve all users in the list, but all of the users in the list with the exception of the current users, for ultimately the current user would be matched with a user. But looking at this code now, it doesn't seem to achieve that. If the list of users is empty, can't it just return an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the following line of code

```
  ParseUser user = mUsers.get(5);
```

mUsers.get(5) is probably null, or doesn't exist. There is nothing in your code which guarantees that the list has to be at least size 5.

Try this instead

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.matching);

    //create list variable
    mUsers = new List<ParseUser>(); 
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {

    ...

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() 
    {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) 
        {
            if (e == null) 
            {
                //add all the users to your list variable 
                mUsers.addAll(users); 

                //check the size of your list to see how big it is before accessing it
                final int size = mUsers.size(); 

                //or use a loop to loop through each one
                for(ParseUser mParseUser : mUsers)
                {
                    //skip over the current user
                    if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser())
                           continue; 

                    //use the correct type when getting
                     final String mName = user.getString("name");
                     final int mNumber = user.getNumber("age"); 
                     final String mHeadLine = user.getString("headline");
                 }


            } 

           else 
           {
                // Something went wrong.
           }

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response man. I do however, have an issue - I do not want to retrieve all users in the list, but all of the users in the list with the exception of the current users, for ultimately the current user would be matched with a user.

Comment: Simple put for(ParseUder mParseUser : mUsers){ if(mParseUser == ParseUser.getCurrentUser()) continue; }, ill update the code above

Comment: There's also the issue of async code, the `findInBackground()` will do just that, do a background request. the `for()` request will (usually) be hit before the background task has finished, so at that point `mUsers` will still be empty.

Comment: Thanks brother for your response, I have greatly appreciated your inputs. This has helped clarified much. If you don't mind I do have two minor issues left to be resolved. The first one is kinda of basic, and pretty much deals with a few formatting errors, and I admittedly admit that I need to gain a stronger foundation in java, the second issue is a bit more complex, and I can address it to you if you don't mind.

Comment: Timothy walters is correct, make sure you put the loop in the if(e== null) {} area, since that occurs on the main thread and after everything has been retrieved in the background. if you need more help you can message me or simple ask another question here, there's plenty of us here to help you. Also, making sure your foundation is solid with Java is paramount before beginning android. I recommend Tony Gaddis Java book, and then Core Java. It might take about 30+ days to complete, but afterwards your foundation will be SOLID. =)